# Tuncate string in ASP.NET using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, truncate

I made a function to truncate a string in the code behind file. But how do i use it in the aspx file?

This is the textbox:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="page" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href='<%# makepageURL( Eval("page") )%> '>
            <%# Eval("page")%>
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtpage" TextMode="SingleLine" Rows="1" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<% #Bind("page") %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And this is my function:

```
Public Function TrimString(ByVal Value As String, ByVal Length As Integer) As String
    If Value.Length > 20 Then
        Return Value.Substring(Value.Length - (20 - 3)) + "..."
    End If

    Return Value   
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an issue of *how* to use it, but actually *when* to use it?

If you had a regular span, you could do this:

```
<span><%: TrimString("somestring") %></span>
```

But this is a **TextBox** your dealing with (user input).

**When** should it truncate?

On Form Submit? (that would make sense).

As they type (well then you'd need to use JavaScript).

By the looks of your code snipper, your using a FormView.

So i wouldn't be calling it from the ASPX (which the equivalent of executing code during Page Render), i would be calling it during the Edit/Submit event, server-side event handler.

In other words, truncate the value the user put in, after they have submitted the form and before you persist to the database.

Comment: The posted snippet will _not_ work. You can't use `<%%>` (code blocks) inside a server side control.

Comment: No actually i should be truncated when they 'view' it. I edited my first post. forgot to paste the complete template

Comment: @Yustme - i haven't used FormView in a while, but assume you have a DataBind event in the code behind? can't you truncate each row as you databind?

Comment: Okay, let us know how you get on - and don't forget to tick this as the correct answer if it helped.